# shell - put variable in ALPHABETICAL range of cycle

Tags: bash, variables, range, alphabetical

is there some way to put variable in ALPHABETICAL range of cycle?
This doesnt work.

```
read -p "Where I should start?" start #there will be entered one small letter
for aaa in {$start..z}; do #how put variable $start in range?
...
done
```

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3):

Use `eval` to expand the variable:

```
$ s=t
$ eval echo {$s..z}
t u v w x y z
```

Your example then becomes:

```
read -p "Where I should start?" start #there will be entered one small letter
for aaa in $(eval echo {$start..z}); do 
echo $aaa
done
```

Since you have user input to `eval`, you may want to check the value of start as being a single lower case character first:

```
read -p "Where I should start?" start #there will be entered one small letter
if [[ $start =~ ^[a-y]$ ]]; then 
   for aaa in $(eval echo {$start..z}); do 
   echo $aaa
   done
else 
   echo "Need to use a letter 'a-y'"
fi
```

You can read more about Bash brace expansion [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace)

Comment: Why would you do something as simple as that? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't put variables inside `{start..end}` ranges in bash.

This does what you want:

```
until [[ $s == "_" ]]; do echo $s && s=$(tr "a-z" "b-z_" <<<$s); done
```

It uses `tr` to translate each character to the next one. "_" is the character after "z".

For example:

```
$ s=t
$ until [[ $s == "_" ]]; do echo $s && s=$(tr "a-z" "b-z_" <<<$s); done
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

If you don't mind using Perl, you could use this:

```
perl -le 'print for shift .. "z"' $s
```

It uses `..` to create a list between the first argument on the command line and "z".

A slightly more esoteric way to do it in bash would be:

```
for ((i=$(LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$s"); i<=122; ++i)); do 
    printf "\\$(printf '%03o' $i)\n" 
done
```

The `for` loop goes from the ASCII character number of the variable `$s` to "z", which is ASCII character 122. The format specifier the inner `printf` converts the character number to octal, padding it with zeros up to three characters long. The outer `printf` then interprets this as an escape sequence and prints the character. *Credit goes to [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) for the code used to convert ASCII characters to their values*.

Of course you could just use `eval` to expand the variable, the advantage being that the code required to do so is much shorter. However, executing arbitrary strings that have been read in to your script is arguably a bit of a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=t
for I in $(sed -nr "s/.*($x.*)/\1/;s/ /\n/g;p" <(echo {a..z}))
do 
  # do something with $I
done
```

Output:

```
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the use of `eval`.

```
for aaa in {a..z}; do
    [[ $aaa < $start ]] && continue
    ...
done
```

The overhead of comparing `$aaa` to `$start` should be negligible, especially compare to the cost of starting a separate process to compute the range.